# Are Apache logs needed when Piwik is being used

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

Do I need to keep Apache access logs if I'm using Piwik for analytics (or Google Analytics)?

True, these could serve as a backup. However, rotation would remove a certain history from the logs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of web server access logs is that they are entirely within your control. Because Google Analytics and Piwiks rely on javascript run within the user's browser, the user can disable them, or modify their activity.

For security purposes alone I would recommend retaining at least *some* of your web server logs.

Comment: Exactly this - logs aren't just to count visitors, they're there to help you support the server.